# iPhone - Where is the brightness/backlight level setting in the file system?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, jailbreak

I have an iPhone that was dropped in water. Once the backlight level goes below a certain point, the screen is completely black/useless. I need to go in iFile or some other file system browsing software to set the brightness level to 80% or something high. I've looked around and found the backlight level for SB Settings but I'm not sure if that will work. Anybody know where that setting is?

Comment: Well I got the phone working again. I found the "SBBacklightLevel2" property in "com.apple.springboard.plist". I set it to .9, rebooted the phone and the screen worked. I'd still like to know where the system brightness property is though. THanks!

Comment: That's the file and property that you're looking for. I saw this question as was about to post exactly what you had already found, but then I saw your comment.

Comment: Oh ok, for some reason I was thinking the property I found was referring to a SBSettings property and not for the system. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! (In fact, most SBSettings toggles directly modify values in system `.plist`'s such as this.)

Answer (score 1):

User > Library > Preferences. The property is called "SBBacklightLevel2" in the com.apple.springboard.plist file.
Thanks @Andrew Larsson for the confirmation of this.